# Passing value from for loop in ajax, into form field

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have some javascript that takes user input, queries an endpoint with that input via ajax, and returns a field from the results as an appended `<option>` to a `datalist`. This is working properly and I see exactly what I need in the options list.

The next portion I've worked on is that when I click the option, I want other fields related to it in the object to populate the value of a form input. I've got this all structured but when I click an item it says `result is not defined`
in this line:

```
$("#groupName").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.name);
```

So my options are correct, and when I click an option it reflects the clicked option in the console. The issue is that I'm not passing the result into my `else if` correctly, apparently.

The heirarchy of my _source is correct but I just don't know how I need to change my .val argument in order to pull the right value.

Any ideas?

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function () {
  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ((foundOption = $('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector)).length) {
    console.log(optSelector); //this prints the option[value] of the clicked value as it should
    $("#groupName").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.name);
    $("#groupNum").val(result[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source.code);
  } else {

    const searchResult = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result:searchResult
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        console.log(searchResult);
        $("#returnedProducts").empty();

        let result = response.hits.hits;

        console.log(result);
        for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append("<option srindex=" + [i] + " value=" + result[i]._source.name + ">" + result[i]._source.name + "</option>");


        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Update:
my object looks like this

```
hits
  hits
    _source
      name
      code
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qhbt569o/8/

Comment: Try to give us a live working simple that reproduces your problem, please.

Comment: Yes, check my answer

Comment: I gave you an updated link to the fiddle with /8 on it. It does have _source. But again, getting the value from my json isn't the problem, it's putting the value into another input. Check my link to you above that ends in /8

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki did you see my comment below? This works in the fiddle but my 'result' is defined in the ajax success in my code so this still doesn't work. can I pass it from my ajax to my if else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/qhbt569o/13/)**.

You've just to change `_source` by `source` inside the loop like :

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  $("#returnedProducts").append("<option srindex=" + [i] + " value=" + result[i].source.name + ">" + result[i].source.name + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qhbt569o/8 check this link for my problem. I don't have issue getting from json, my issue is passing the value to my other input

Comment: Ok I'll check it

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/qhbt569o/15/ , you've just to add the jquery to the fiddle to pass the value to the input.

Comment: Wow that's it! Thanks so much

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Comment: Wait I found the issue: It works on the fiddle but not in my code because in the fiddle I put the JSON as a variable,  but in my code 'result' comes from within my ajax success portion. How can I pass it out of ther?